# Show result of multiple criteria with the highest sum

Tags: excel-formula

Please can you kindly help me solve the below.

What is the formula to go into cell H2?

Show the value in D2:D11 with the highest sum total in E2:E11 when:

the value in C2:C11 = "Fizzy" &

when the value in B2:B11 = "Drink" &

when the value in A2:A11 = G2

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the sum, there is a pivot table needed.
As the column D is sorted by brand the following workaround is possible.
Please add in column `F2`

```
=E2+IF(D2=D1,E2,0)
```

And copy this to all rows below.
Or include all your condition:

```
=IF(AND(B2="Drink",C2="Fizzy"),E2,0)+IF(D2=D1,E2,0)
```

In H2 please enter for the largest value

```
=LET(maxvalue,max( (C2:C11="Fizzy")*(B2:B11="Drink")*(E2:E11) ) , concat(if(E2:E11=maxvalue,D2:D11,"") ) )
```

or for the largest sum (with column F):

```
=LET(maxvalue,max( (F2:F11) ) , concat(if(F2:F11=maxvalue,D2:D11,"") ) )
```